# Run CATIA VBA macro in batch mode from Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net, vba, catia

I have created a VB class to manipulate a CATIA project. The VB code is compiled into a dll loaded into a C# project.

```
Imports ProductStructureTypeLib
Imports INFITF
Imports MECMOD

Public Class MyCATIAClass
    Private catia As INFITF.Application

    Public Sub New()
        catia = GetObject(, "CATIA.Application")
    End Sub

    Public Sub doStuff()
        ' do stuff
    End Sub

End Class
```

And in C#:

```
MyCATIAClass catOb = new MyCATIAClass();
catOb.doStuff();
```

This works just fine. My question is: Is it possible to run the method in batch mode? this would significantly increase the performance at run time.

Answer (score 0):

you better create a batch file (and call the vbfile from inside it) and run it from the c# code by the following code
*Process.Start("path of your batch file\nameOfBatchFile.bat")*

Before that to create a batch file in a note pad write the following commands 
and save it as fileName.bat

```
@echo on
cd path of vbfileName    
start vbfileName
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to execute tasks without visualization, it was enough to set the visible property to false.

```
Imports ProductStructureTypeLib
Imports INFITF
Imports MECMOD

Public Class MyCATIAClass
Private catia As INFITF.Application

Public Sub New()
    catia = GetObject(, "CATIA.Application")
End Sub

Public Sub doStuff()
    catia.Visible = False
    ' do stuff
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0):

start CATIA in Batch:
"C:\cv5\B20\win_b64\code\bin\CNEXT.exe -batch -env CATIA.V5R20.B20 -direnv C:\cv5env\CATEnv"

Answer (score 0):

We can use CATStart for batch mode:

```
CATSTART.exe –direnv C:\CATEnv –env CATIA.V5R30 -object “-batch -macro C:\Temp\BatchTest\DwgParamBatch.CATScript”
```